# Updating Laravel ManyToMany Relationship without deleting(or detaching)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

**Goal** - Update many-to-many relationship but not to delete rows

Suppose, User & Role models have many-to-many relationship. A particular `$user` **has three roles - [1,2,3]**. It **means there are three rows in the pivot table** for this `$user`.

Now, I want to update the relationship. I want the roles now to be [1,2,4]. I don't want to delete the rows on pivot table (because this will lead to a gap in the IDs of pivot table). If I use `sync([1,2,4])`, it will delete the row corresponding to role '3'. If I use `sync([1,2,4],false)`, it will keep the row with role '3'. I want the role '3' to be updated to '4' without any deletion. How can this be achieved?

I am aware of `detach()` function but that again deletes the rows.

**EDIT: ORIGIN OF THE QUESTION**

If I have a many-to-many relationship between `User` & `Role` models & often the **roles for a user keep changing**. So, **is it better to keep detaching old roles & attaching new roles?** Or, I should update the `role_id` on existing rows of the pivot table without deleting/detaching existing rows?

I am concerned about this because if I delete a row & add another one, the `'id'` gets incremented & there is a gap in place of the previous `'id'`. **If I have millions of users & thousands of roles, wouldn't the 'id' getting bigger be causing a problem to me in future?**

If it exceeds integer limits, I know it will not exceed bigInt limit(most probably). That's fine. But I read somewhere, as the IDs get bigger, the performance gets lower.

Can someone please tell me the best practice for this?

Comment: I think you shouldn't really be worried about the IDs in your pivot tables. What's the reason behind this concern?

Comment: @lukasgeiter What if they get too big & give performance issues later? What if sometime (not in near future) they exceed integer limits? I just want to know the best practice for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about deleting and adding records in your pivot table.
Regarding the size of your IDs, the [maximum value of an unsigned INT in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) is **4'294'967'295**. I don't believe you will reach that very soon. If you still are concerned you can:

1. Use a unsigned BIGINT (max 18446744073709551615)
2. Just remove the ID entirely, it's often not needed in pivot tables.

Comment: Suppose, I don't follow second option, wouldn't there be performance issues as the IDs get bigger?

Comment: I'm not really a database expert but as far as I know using a BIGINT has some performance implications, but the actual size of the number doesn't matter. Meaning if you have records with ids from 0-1000 or 10000-11000 doesn't change anything. I think you can really stick to a normal unsigned INT. *If* your application happens to be used that much you can still do something about it later...